# How do I adjust the formatting of a Word table row to match the rest of the table?

Tags: microsoft-word

I copied some rows from a different table, now those rows have a different length and cell sizes than the other rows of the table. Is there a way to automatically adjust the layout of the row to match the rest of the table?

(My version is Word 2003)

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate **Smart Cut and Paste** in settings so **Adjust table formatting and alignment on paste** is selected.

1. Got to `Tools > Options`, then the `Edit` tab
2. Under `Cut and paste options` check the `Smart Cut and Paste` option
3. Click the <kbd>Settings...</kbd> button
4. Make sure the `Adjust table formatting and alignment on paste` check
   box is selected.
5. `OK` back out

[image]

[image]

Sources:
[Word: Pasting a row into a table doesn’t keep the column widths](http://cybertext.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/word-pasting-a-row-into-a-table-doesnt-keep-the-column-widths/)
[Options used for "Smart cut and paste" settings in Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297680)